# TemperatureControl trait confusion

Tags: actions-on-google

I have just started with Google Actions. The first trait we want to support is the temperature reading from my device. It's not a thermostat so we'll need to use TemperatureControl trait (readonly-sensor, no control) .

The issue is that after implementing TemperatureControl, I can't request Google Assistant to read out the temperature. Has anyone encountered similar issue? I have search the topic on TemperatureControl, seems there was none similar issue reported. Thanks in advance.

The more detail flow is:

ask "What's the temperature in Bedroom?"

- I receive a QUERY intent in my backend server and responded with Ambient Temperature

  but, the answer is "Sorry I can't reach the bedroom right now. Please try again"
- After that, I tried to add HumiditySetting Trait to verify my SYNC/ QUERY validity. 
  This is working.

  ask "What's the Humidity level in Bedroom?"
- I receive a QUERY intent in my backend server and responded with Ambient Humidity. Actually it's the same response as in the case of Temperature.

  but, the answer is "the bedroom has a current humidity reading of xx%"
- My SYNC Response is validated with https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/validator
  Below is a sample:

```
{
    "requestId": "10692316150281033205",
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "1-5671",
        "devices": [
            {
                "id": "3466",
                "type": "action.devices.types.CAMERA",
                "traits"[
                    "action.devices.traits.HumiditySetting",
                    "action.devices.traits.TemperatureControl"
                ],
                "name": {
                    "defaultNames": [
                        "bedroom"
                    ],
                    "name": "bedroom",
                    "nicknames": [
                        "bedroom"
                    ]
                },
                "willReportState": true,
                "roomHint": null,
                "deviceInfo": null,
                "otherDeviceIds": null,
                "customData": {
                    "deviceId": "CQAMNGF"
                },
                "attributes": {
                    "temperatureUnitForUX": "C",
                    "queryOnlyHumiditySetting": true,
                    "queryOnlyTemperatureControl": true
                }
            }
        ],
        "errorCode": null
    }
}
```

Comment: try to format your steps using the bullet or numbered list for readability.

Comment: Can you give a query for the device itself? Does it change if you give it a more specific name rather than the room name?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I was using thermostatTemperatureSetpoint and thermostatTemperatureAmbient in Query response.

After changing them back to temperatureSetpointCelsius
temperatureAmbientCelsius, it works.